# Setting numeric constraints on variables

Tags: vba, excel, constraints

Is there a way to put constraints when creating variables in VBA?

Example:
*dim alfa as integer*

Now I'd like Excel to accept **only values from 0 up to 99**, how can I do that?

many thanks

Comment: Validate the value at the time of assignment.

Comment: Ok, but how? dim alfa as integer then?

Comment: You haven't given any information as to how the variable gets a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could validate it like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 100

    If Not (i >= 0 And i <= 99) Then Err.Raise Number:=6, Description:="Number not valid"

    'continue to use i
End Sub
```

---

You could also create a new class, which would only accept certain values. In most cases this would be overkill, but here it is:

Put this into a standard module

```
Sub Test()
    Dim specialNumber As SNumber
    Set specialNumber = New SNumber

    specialNumber.Value = 1
    specialNumber.Value = 100 'this line will throw an error
End Sub
```

Then put this into a class module and name the module **SNumber**

```
Private specialNumber As Integer

Public Property Get Value() As Integer
    Value = specialNumber
End Property

Public Property Let Value(v As Integer)
    If Not (v >= 0 And v <= 99) Then
        Err.Raise Number:=6, Description:="Number not valid"
    Else
        specialNumber = v
    End If
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do it is to use data validation in Excel.

```
Sub TestMe()
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
              Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=AND(A1>=0, A1<=100, ISNUMBER(A1))"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Now `A1` would be only between 1 and 100 and it would be a number.